# BQ25570 Ground Layout

Tags: ground, energy-harvesting

I am using the [BQ25570](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25570.pdf) power management IC for energy harvesting from a solar panel. I am currently designing the PCB layout for the IC, and I am a bit confused about the ground. As you can see in page 4 of the datasheet, there exist two separate VSS pins. In the typical applications (for example 8.2.1, pg 25) all grounds are noted with the same ground symbol. Lastly in 10.1, pg 34, the second paragraph makes a reference to the ground practice. Also, pg 35 you can see a layout example.

I would like to see how do you interpret the above-mentioned information (that is, where would you connect each ground), as I am not 100% sure about the best solution.

If I am not mistaken, in the layout example, both VSS pins are connected to the same ground plane. What about the PowerPad of the IC?

Comment: Although all VSS pins go to ground potential, they carry very different currents. Follow the layout example, figure 48 page 35, in the data sheet you've linked to. Do not change its topology unless you have figured out all the current flows, what residual voltages they create, and whether those matter in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a switching power supply, large current spikes will flow through the ground power path.  Since our conductors are not perfect, parasitic inductance and resistive losses can cause voltage differences from one ground point to another.  In sensitive circuits, this voltage difference can cause problems.  This is why the manufacturer of the chip has given you the option to separate the grounds to isolate the large current paths to specific pins.  The implementation would be to tie the two grounds together at a single point, through a jumper or zero ohm resistor for instance.

In spite of the words that are contained in the datasheet and the layout guide to separate the grounds, the example design directly connects both VSS pins and the PowerPad to ground.